# Order SSRS Report by Dimension property in MDX

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, mdx, olap-cube

I have MDX query where I want to ORDER all my sheet by `nPosicion` So I do something like this:

```
 //MEASURES THERE     
   ON COLUMNS,  
    NON EMPTY { (
    ORDER ([Dim BSC].[nPosicion].CURRENTMEMBER,[Dim BSC].[nPosicion].CURRENTMEMBER,BDESC) 
    *FILTER([Dim Tiempo].[Anio].CHILDREN, [Dim Tiempo].[Anio].CURRENTMEMBER  =  [Dim Tiempo].[Anio].&[2018]) 
    *FILTER([Dim Tiempo].[Mes].CHILDREN, [Dim Tiempo].[Mes].CURRENTMEMBER  =  [Dim Tiempo].[Mes].&[2])

      [Dim Tiempo].[NmontName].[NmontName].ALLMEMBERS  //etc
```

As you can see I use   `ORDER ([Dim BSC].[nPosicion].CURRENTMEMBER,[Dim BSC].[nPosicion].CURRENTMEMBER,BDESC)`  to try to order my sheet but it just no order nothing.  I'm missing something in order clause? Regards

Report photo
[image]

Parameter Photo:

[image]

Comment: So you're saying there is no order in your query results or when the report is displayed?.. You may need to specify your ordering in the report itself.

Comment: When report is displayed and query results are not order too, how can I specify order of all sheet. I don't want to add only into tablix or row, I want to add it globaly to all report sheets @BJones

Comment: Do you have multiple tablixes?.. Or one tablix that spits out multiple pages? I would specify ordering in the group properties under sorting.

Comment: I have multiple tablefixes, look photo of my report.When I execute report  I have Parameter called bsc if I send bsc 1 it load me one page, if I send it as 1,2 it load me 2 pages  with different information @BJones

Comment: Yeah I can see you have two groups on the middle two rows. Use those groups to sort your data. What are you trying to sort?

Comment: It should no work if I added to groups because I have report title and anothers fields who no are into table... Thats why  I need to apply to sheet, so logic is insert into DataSource as I try but it no works @BJones

Comment: @David I added to my answer - please can you post your complete MDX script rather than just the snippet

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the ORDER function needs to be a set expression

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/order-mdx

You have used a member expression as the first argument because `CURRENTMEMBER` returns a member not a set.

---

Let me illustrate what you are doing with `CURRENTMEMBER`

A very simple script:

```
SELECT 
  [Date].[Date].[All Periods] ON 0,
  NON EMPTY  [Product].[Product].[Product] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Gives this:

[image]

So if I change to your structure:

```
SELECT 
  [Date].[Date].[All Periods] ON 0,
  NON EMPTY  
    ORDER(
        [Product].[Product].CURRENTMEMBER,
        [Product].[Product].CURRENTMEMBER,
        BDESC
    ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

I get this:

[image]

This is a correct way of using ORDER - it requires a set as the first argument and an expression to order by as the second - in the following I am ordering alphabetically descending:

```
SELECT 
  [Date].[Date].[All Periods] ON 0,
  NON EMPTY  
    ORDER(
        [Product].[Product].[Product].MEMBERS,            //<<this returns a SET
        [Product].[Product].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION, //<<this is what will be used to decide the order
        BDESC
    ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Returns this with the data ordered correctly:

[image]

So a possibility for you is to change to something like the following:

```
ORDER (
  [Dim BSC].[nPosicion].[nPosicion].MEMBERS,
  [Dim BSC].[nPosicion].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE, //<<you may need to try [Dim BSC].[nPosicion].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION
  BDESC
)
```

---

I also noticed other errors in your mdx:

```
FILTER(
    [Dim Tiempo].[Anio].CHILDREN, 
    [Dim Tiempo].[Anio].CURRENTMEMBER  =  [Dim Tiempo].[Anio].&[2018]
)
```

You need to change the `=` to `IS`:

```
FILTER(
    [Dim Tiempo].[Anio].CHILDREN, 
    [Dim Tiempo].[Anio].CURRENTMEMBER  IS  [Dim Tiempo].[Anio].&[2018]
)
```

Although why bother with the filter at all and just replace with the following:

```
{ [Dim Tiempo].[Anio].&[2018] }
```